# Fit image to screen height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to scale an image to the screen height. I'm using `style="max-height:100%; width:auto; display: block;"` to fit it to the screen height, and `margin:0px auto;` to center it. This work on Chrome browser but don't work on Firefox. I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to do is fit the image size to the **viewport's** height, not the screen's.

The viewport is the actual portion of the screen where your app will be rendered (browser window - browser interface).

To achieve that, you could use `height: 100vh`, where one `1vh` is equal to 1% of the viewport's height.

Thus, your image will always be exactly as tall as the viewport, that is the "screen" in your case.

Comment: The vh unit is relatively new. See http://caniuse.com/viewport-units to see where it is supported.

Comment: IE 8<, Opera Mini and old versions of Android&Blackberry browsers are the only ones who do not support this. I mean, the 5 major browsers support it even if you go 2 versions back on each of them. That's pretty decent support if you ask me. However, it shouldn't be hard to detect IE8< and calculate the viewport's height using JS, should it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set
`position: fixed` for the image.

When set image size will be cropped to fit the size of the viewport.